# Bootstrap data-toggle open above issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make bootstrap data-toggle to open up above `Click to add` button.
I did so by adding a class `.open-above`.But its opening from top rather than botton.

How can I achieve the same open functionality like it was opening by removing `.open-above` class only that it should open above the button.

```
.open-above{
  bottom:75px;
}
```

Please find link [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/lkRlCwcNuRYWTwk9uYQm?p=previewe)

Comment: remove bottom:75px it will come below to click to add button

Comment: remove bottom 75px from this class .open-above{
  bottom:75px; 
} and try

Comment: yes remove that line from style.css

Comment: On removing the class toggle drop-down is opening bottom side(which is by default).I want it to open above the button with same transition effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try slide toggle instead of a collapsible panel?

```
slideToggle()
```

Something like this  http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8LXY6/

Comment: I need the same behaviour using bootstrap `data-toggle="collapse"`.I wanted to add this in angular2 project.So can't use jquery